# animated convolution in PStricks

Tags: xetex, pstricks, animations

how to create animated convolution of two arbitrary function  in pstricks like [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/convolution-of-two-functions/)

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

There maybe a problem with `XeLaTeX`  and Javascript from the package `animate`. In that case use `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot,animate}
\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls,autoplay,
  begin={\psset{unit=2}\begin{pspicture*}(-2.2,-0.5)(2.2,5.5)},
  end={\end{pspicture*}}]{8}
%       % Generate frames for -2 ... 2
  \multiframe{40}{rA=-2.0+0.1}{%
    \rput(0,3){%
      \psaxes[Dy=0.5,dy=0.5,ticksize=-4pt 0,subticks=5](0,0)(-2,0)(2,1)[$\tau$,0][$f$,90]
      \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt](-0.5,0)(-0.5,1)(0.5,1)(0.5,0)
      \psline[linecolor=green,linewidth=1pt,strokeopacity=0.5]%
            (!\rA\space -0.5 add 0)(!\rA\space -0.5 add 1)(!\rA\space 0.5 add 1)(!\rA\space 0.5 add 0)%
    }%
    \ifdim\rA pt>-1pt  
      \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-1}{\rA\space dup 1 gt {pop 1} if}{x dup 0 gt { neg } if 1 add }
    \fi
    \psline[linecolor=green,linestyle=dashed](\rA,0)(\rA,4.5)
    \psaxes[Dy=0.5,dy=0.5,ticksize=-4pt 0,subticks=5](0,0)(-2,0)(2,1)[$t$,0][,0]
    \rput(0,2){$\displaystyle f*g=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau)g(t-\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau$}
}       
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

If you want to use `\psConv` then replace

```
    \ifdim\rA pt>-1pt  
      \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-1}{\rA\space dup 1 gt {pop 1} if}{x dup 0 gt { neg } if 1 add }
    \fi
```

with

```
    \psConv[plotpoints=100,Simpson=1000,linecolor=red]{-2}{\rA}(-10,10)%
          {abs 0.5 le {1} {0} ifelse}{abs 0.5 le {1} {0} ifelse}%
```

and, of course, load the package `pst-func`. The conversion of the pdf into a gif I used:

```
 convert -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 -scale 300 -alpha remove <file>.pdf <file>.gif
```

Comment: can i use \psConv  for convolved function

Comment: see at the end of the edited answer